# VBA - MySQL UPDATE - Return code to confirm Update was done or not

Tags: mysql, vba

Trying to run a MySQL update in Excel.

Would like to check if the UPDATE happened or not, i.e. was the row found and updated or such a row does not exist and 0 rows were updated

Tried to find a return code from MySQL in the VBA code but nothing I am at a loss!

```
c = 2
Do While Trim(MAIN.Cells(c, 1)) <> ""

   sMyword = "UPDATE table1 SET price = 1.00 WHERE part = 'ABC';"
   conn.Execute sMyword

   If "did the update happen against the row" > 0 Then
       MAIN.Cells(c, 3) = "Price UPDATED OK"
   Else
       MAIN.Cells(c, 3) = "Part NOT FOUND "
       MAIN.Cells(c, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
   End If

   c = c + 1

Loop
```

I wish to get the number of rows updated by the SQL statement `sMyword`

Answer (score 0):

The Execute method should return the affected records in a second argument `RecordsAffected`. Try this syntax:

```
Dim RecordsAffected As Long
sMyword = "UPDATE table1 SET price = 1.00 WHERE part = 'ABC';"
conn.Execute sMyword, RecordsAffected
MsgBox RecordsAffected
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-connection?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, Managed to get it to work using RecordsAffected - so the query became 
 `conn.Execute sMyword, RecordsAffected`

Comment: Awesome, please upvote my answer if it helped you. Also I changed the variable name to RecordsAffected to be a more accurate and complete answer.